# Separating positive even, positive odd, negative odd, and negative even numbers into new arrays

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to separate the -odd, -even, even, and odds into separate arrays.  I have done this in matlab but confused with how this would work in python.  All I got so far is how to generate a user inputted array

```
print('Enter 10 numbers: ')
num=10
l1=[0]*num

for l in range (0,num):
    numbers = float(input('Enter value #'+str(l+1)+' : '))   
    l1[l]=numbers  
print('Your numbers are: ',l1 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example that does what you need and starts with your code to populate the "l1" list.

```
negative_odds = []
negative_evens = []
evens = []
odds = []

for num in l1:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        if num < 0:
            negative_evens.append(num)
        else:
            evens.append(num)
    else:
        if num < 0:
            negative_odds.append(num)
        else:
            odds.append(num)

print('-odd: ', negative_odds)
print('-even: ', negative_evens)
print('even: ', evens)
print('odd: ', odds)
```